# Object instances as list elements

Tags: python, oop

I've written the below on a whim after being reading about the "METHINKS IT IS LIKE A WEASEL" algorithm. What I expect to happen in pop_gen() is for ten instances of Gib to be created - each with a randomised name - and stored in the list popul. What I get instead is a list of instances with the same name. I *think* that I'm actually only creating one instance then referring to it ten times, but I can't figure out why - I've tried doing it with a for loop instead of a list comprehension, and passing randomised names as variables instead of randomising in the Gib class itself.

```
import random
import string

class Evolver:
    def __init__(self, input_text, chance):
        self.input_text = list(input_text)
        self.gib_text = [random.choice(chars) for c in self.input_text]
        self.chance = chance
        self.popul = []

    def pop_gen(self):
        temp_popul = [Gib(self.gib_text, self.chance) for i in range(10)]
        self.popul = temp_popul

class Gib:
    def __init__(self, gib_text, chance):
        self.name = self.mutator(gib_text, chance)
        self.score = 0

    def mutator(self, gib_text, chance):
        for c in range(len(gib_text)):
            if chance >= random.randint(1, 100):
                gib_text[c] = random.choice(chars)
        return gib_text

chars = string.uppercase

e = Evolver("TEST", 100)
e.pop_gen()

for p in e.popul:
    print p, p.name
```

Any and all help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating 10 seperate instances *with the same name*.  Since `Gib.name` ends up being a list, when you mutate it in `Gib.mutator`, all references to that list see the change.  When you create the `Gib`s in the first place, you pass them the same list (`self.gib_text`), so they all share the same list for a `name` and therefore they all end up with the same name (even if it gets mutated in `Gib.mutator`).  One workaround is to copy `self.gib_text` when you pass it to the initializer:

```
def pop_gen(self):
    temp_popul = [Gib(self.gib_text[:], self.chance) for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: I considered this before and moved the functionality of the mutator method so that the randomised name was passed when instantiating the class, but that didn't seem to resolve it. I'll give this another go!

Comment: @TKC -- No problem.  Another thing is that your `mutator` never uses `self`.  You could make it a regular function or a `staticmethod` (removing `self` from the argument list in either case).